# Visualization of simple topological spaces

Tags: general-topology, intuition, visualization

I am not so good with visualizing some spaces and would appreciate if you help me.

1. Are my drawings of the topological spaces correct?
2. Why does $\mathbb{R^2} X S^1$ look like torus **without boundary**? (If it is correct). Could you describe, how to "fold and glue the $\mathbb{R^2}$ with the $S^1$ to obtain the torus? If this is non-compact, should I imagine "infinite" torus?
3. Do product topological spaces usually have product topology as "default" choice? Or what other intereseting topologies could they admit?

Thank you very much.

Remarks:
In #4, I mean the closure of $\mathbb{R} \times [0;1]$ in $\mathbb{R^2}$.

[image: My sketches]

Comment: Your third drawing isn't good: $\mathbb{R}^2\times S^1$ is not compact. It is quite hard to sketch it right as it is a non-compact 3 dimensional space that is different from the usual 3D space

Comment: Note that $\mathbb{R}^2$ is hoemorphic to the open disc $\mathring{D}$. That's why $\mathbb{R}^2\times S^1 \cong \mathring{D}\times S^1$ is the torus without its boundary.

Comment: @Didier Hmm, but I assumed that $\mathbb{R^2} X S^1$ is homeomorphic to $D^2 X S^1$ which should look like this, according to Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_torus. So why would you say it doesn´t look like the torus without boundary? Should I imagine, that the torus just has the 2-dimensinal hole, but then "escapes to infinity" in all directions?

Comment: you can write the symbol for the cartesian product in LaTeX via \times btw.

Comment: @Didier, the solid torus without it's boundary is non compact

Comment: What definition are you using for the overline notation in 4?

Comment: Yeah, $\overline{\mathbb R\times[0,1]}$ needs definition. Usually $\overline{Y}$ is the closure of $Y$ in some other space, $X.$ Here, you’ve specified $Y,$ but not $X.$

Comment: @DavidSheard Closure of the space (added this remark into the question)

Comment: Closure of the space in what space, @TerezaTizkova

Comment: In that case, $\mathbb{R}$ and $[0,1]$ are already closed (in the subset topology on $\mathbb{R}$, and so their product is already closed (in the subset topology on $\mathbb{R}^2$). So the pictures for 1 and 4 are the same.

Comment: @DavidSheard Yes, but the drawing does not say "without the boundary". I agree that what you said is true

Comment: @ThomasAndrews You are right, I added the updates. It is in $\mathbb{R^2}$.

Comment: It is already closed in $\mathbb R^2.$ @TerezaTizkova